# Use an expression for $\frac{\sin(5\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}$ to find the roots of the equation $x^4-3x^2+1=0$ in trigonometric form

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, roots

> > Question: Use an expression for $\frac{\sin(5\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}$ , ($\theta \neq k \pi)$ , k an integer to find the roots of the equation $x^4-3x^2+1=0$ in trigonometric form?

---

What I have done

By using demovires theorem and expanding

$$ cis(5\theta) = (\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta))^5$$

$$ \cos(5\theta) + i \sin(5\theta) = \cos^5(\theta) - 10\cos^3(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)  + 5\cos(\theta)\sin^4(\theta) +i(5\cos^4(\theta)\sin(\theta)-10\cos^2(\theta)\sin^3(\theta) + \sin^5(\theta)$$

Considering only $Im(z) = \sin(5\theta)$

$$ \sin(5\theta) = 5\cos^4(\theta)\sin(\theta)-10\cos^2(\theta)\sin^3(\theta) + \sin^5(\theta) $$

$$ \therefore \frac{\sin(5\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} = \frac{5\cos^4(\theta)\sin(\theta)-10\cos^2(\theta)\sin^3(\theta) + \sin^5(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}$$

$$ \frac{\sin(5\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} = 5\cos^4(\theta) -10\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta) + \sin^4(\theta)  $$

How should I proceed , I'm stuck trying to incorporate what I got into the equation..

Comment: $\frac{\sin 5x}{\sin x}=2\cos 4x+2\cos 2x+1$ maybe it helps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Using [Prosthaphaeresis Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html),

$$\sin5x-\sin x=2\sin2x\cos3x=4\sin x\cos x\cos3x$$

If $\sin x\ne0,$
$$\dfrac{\sin5x}{\sin x}-1=4\cos x\cos3x=4\cos x(4\cos^3x-3\cos x)=(4\cos^2x)^2-3(4\cos^2x)$$

OR replace $\sin^2x$ with $1-\cos^2x$ in your $$ 5\cos^4x-10\cos^2x\sin^2x + \sin^4x$$

Now if $\sin5x=0,5x=n\pi$ where $n$ is any integer

$x=\dfrac{n\pi}5$ where $n\equiv0,\pm1,\pm2\pmod5$

So, the roots of
$\dfrac{\sin5x}{\sin x}=0\implies x=\dfrac{n\pi}5$ where $n\equiv\pm1,\pm2\pmod5$

But $$\dfrac{\sin5x}{\sin x}=(4\cos^2x)^2-3(4\cos^2x)+1$$

Comment: Is there anyway of continuing with my way? :(

Comment: @dydxx, Replace $\sin^2x$ with $1-\cos^2x$ and I'll soon finish in my own way